# Lag caused by WoW add-ons

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Before WoD I've mainly been in 10 man guilds and thus lag wasn't really a problem. However with the Mythic content (20 man) and HC/Flex one (up to 30 man) I often experience massive lag.

Now if I disable all add-ons the lag stops but I'm using a lot of them... so the raiding experience isn't optimal without add-ons.

My question is: **Is there a way to find out which add-on is causing this lag?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can actually do that by adding another add-on on top what you have already !
His name is pretty explicit : [Addon usage](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/addon-usage)

If the lag you are talking about is in fact fps drops, look at the CPU usage of each add-on you use to determine which one is using the most, repeat this process until your fps stay constant and you should be good, or you can sacrifice a lot of small add-ons to keep the core ones, that's up to you.

Read carefully the page to have full details and subtilities of the add-on.

Comment: Well let's just hope this addon doesn't cause more lag ;)

Comment: If it does, you can do it the old fashioned way: uninstall everything and then add them back in one by one...

Comment: @Jutschge just keep it for testing, and remove it after.

Comment: @Lin By doing this you can't test all the possible combinations off add-ons (or you have a few months time in front of you) and by testing them one by one, as soon as you are under the "start to lag" limit, you don't have any information about CPU usage. The old-fashioned way has its limits ^^

Comment: @Lin I do it another way. Split your addons list in half, then disable the first half. If it still persists you can ignore the first half and activating them again. And then split the second half in half ect... until you find the one that is annoying you.

Comment: @Lyrion binary searches can be quite effective.

Comment: @Shunwoo No doubt. The old-fashioned way is old-fashioned for a reason.

Comment: @Shunwooo in case you don't already use it, i recommend downloading [Addon controll panel](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/acp). That one allow you to change active addons with a simple reload, thus you won't need to disconnect each time you want to desactivate another addon.

Comment: @Lysarion I think this is standard in WoW aswell, because I haved installed that addon, and I do see aan addons button in my menu. Which also has a reload ui button.

Comment: @Lyrion It is possible, but i came from an era it was not, and never played without ACP since i found it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your UI addons take up a lot, ElveUI etc. Next comes your timers and announcements like Deadly Boss Mods. Lastly your skada/recount will be the Grim Reaper the bigger the raid is. Pay attention to these.

Also, you can turn off addons in game as long as you /reload so that you can efficiently test which addon is the problem.

Lastly, it could jut be an addon out of sync, please always update your addons.